# Trying to open iframe in page with firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm writing code for open iframe in page dom:

**myscript.js**:

```
var url_base = 'http://mydomain.tdl/?from_url=';

var shareUrl =  function () {
  return {
    share : function () {

      var visited_url = gBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;
      var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 800px; height: 600px;");
      iframe.setAttribute("src", url_base+encodeURIComponent(visited_url));

      gBrowser.contentDocument.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
  };
}();
```

**browser.xul**:

```
<menupopup id="menu_ToolsPopup">
    <menuitem label="&urlshare;" key="share-url-run-key" oncommand="shareUrl.share()"/>
</menupopup>
```

How know if my code is **valid** and will work correctly on other machines than my developpement computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you are asking in this question. 
That code correctly creates a options menu item that triggers the creation of an iframe and sets its src as your base url and appends the current page url next to it.

It will show the iframe at the end of the document body.

That will work anywhere.